# merge jquery-1.9.1.min.js and query.mobile-1.3.0.min.js in a single file give error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a jquery mobile webapp

The base structure require jquery.js and jquery-mobile.js ad documented in jqueryMobile doc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myjqueryconfig.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

All works good with this structure but I want to merge jquery js file with jquery-mobile js file to have a single js file but when I do that (simply by cut and pust jquery mobile code to the end of jquery file) page stop working and firebug give me a javascript error:

```
   TypeError: $(...).bind(...) is not a function
```

My single .js file is structured as:

```
//jquery 1.9.1 min source code

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false
})

//jquery mobile min 1.3.0 source code
```

Comment: Ummmm Why would you do that? They are separate files for a reason....

Comment: My framework merge javascript together for client performance. I think they are separate files because they are separate projects, there is any tecnical reason to not have them merged in a single file?

Comment: Did you try adding a `;` between the files when concatenating ?

Comment: @FabianoTaioli how did you merge the files?

Comment: Packaging js and css files together reduce overhead and download time. This is a common wide adopted procedure.

Comment: @Neal simply cut and paste code in one js files. The resulting file have a code structure as i wrote in question. JQUERY source code + my jq mobile config code + JQUERY MOBILE code

Comment: @FabianoTaioli and how did you include it on your page?

Comment: @Neal read the question, this is in there.

Comment: @dystroy thank you... adding ; ad the and of my config code solve the problem. But this is strange ... is not mandatory to have it :) P.S. If you write the answer I give you the check

Comment: @FabianoTaioli I answered with a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a `;` between the files when concatenating them solves the problem.

Look at this code :

```
(function(){
  console.log('A');
}())

(function(){
  console.log('B');
}())
```

Without an intermediary semicolon, the second IIFE looks like an argument passed to the first one. And so it fails. Adding the semicolon solves the problem as it specifies those are two statements.

Semicolons in JavaScript are optional but it's very dangerous to omit them.